# Using nlinfit in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm having trouble understanding and applying the use of `nlinfit` function in Matlab. So, let's say I'm given vectors

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
y = [2.3, 2.1, 1.7, .95, .70]
```

and I'm asked to fit this data to an exponential form (I don't know if the numbers will work, I made them up) where `y = A*e^(Bx) + C` (`A/B/C` are constants).

My understanding is that `nlinfit` takes 4 arguments, the two vectors, a `modelfunction` which in this case should be the equation I have above, and then `beta0`, which I don't understand at all. My question is how do you implement the `modelfunction` in `nlinft`, and how do you find `beta0` (when only working with 2 vectors you want to plot/fit) and how should it be implemented? Can someone show me an example so that I can apply this function for any fit? I suspect I'll be using this a lot in the future and really want to learn it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the second example in the docs: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nlinfit.html

Basically you pass a function handle as your `modelfunction` parameter. Either make a function in a file and then just pass it the function name with an `@` in front or else make an anonymous function like this:

```
nlinfit(x, y, @(b,x)(b(1).*exp(b(2).*x) + b(3)), beta0)
```

You'll notice that in the above I have stuck all your parameters into a single vector. The first parameter of your function must be a vector of all the points you are trying to solve for (i.e. `A`, `B` and `C` in your case) and the second must be `x`.

As woodchips has said `beta0` is your starting point so your best guess (doesn't have to be great) of your `A`, `B` and `C` parameters. so something like `[1 1 1]` or `rand(3,1)`, it is very problem specific though. You should play around with a few. Just remember that this is a local search function and thus can get stuck on local optima so your starting points can actually be quite important.

Answer (score 0):

beta0 is your initial guess at the parameters. The better your guess, the more likely you will see convergence to a viable solution. nlinfit is no more than an optimization. It has to start somewhere.