# Fitting data in least square sense to nonlinear equation

Tags: matlab, least-squares, nonlinear-functions

I need help fitting data in a least square sense to a nonlinear function. Given data, how do I proceed when I have following equation?

f(x) = 20 + ax + b*e^(c*2x)

So I want to find a,b and c. If it was products, I would linearize the function by takin the natural logaritm all over the function but I can not seem to do that in this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`nlinfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nlinfit.html) tool, which doesn't require the Curve Fitting Toolbox (I don't think...)

Something like

```
f = @(b,x)(20 + b(1)*x + b(2)*exp(b(3)*2*x));
beta0 = [1, 1, 1];
beta = nlinfit(x, Y, f, beta0);
```

When MATLAB solves this least-squares problem, it passes the coefficients into the anonymous function `f` in the vector `b`. `nlinfit` returns the final values of these coefficients in the `beta` vector. `beta0` is an initial guess of the values of `b(1)`, `b(2)`, and `b(3)`. `x` and `Y` are the vectors with the data that you want to fit.

Alternatively, you can define the function in its own file, if it is a little more complicated. For this case, you would have something like (in the file `my_function.m`)

```
function y = my_function(b,x)
y = 20 + b(1)*x + b(2)*exp(b(3)*2*x);
end
```

and the rest of the code would look like

```
beta0 = [1, 1, 1];
beta = nlinfit(x, Y, @my_function, beta0);
```

See also: [Using nlinfit in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840099/using-nlinfit-in-matlab)

Comment: @user3342830 Hi! I'm glad it helped :-) If you find this answered your question, can you click the green checkmark below the arrows to show your [acceptance](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) of this answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `cftool` which is an interactive tool for fitting data. The second part I don't quite understand. It may help if you describe it in more detail.